# How to return recursion result and recursion steps as a tuple in Python?

Tags: python, list, recursion, logic

I am trying to return a tuple `(recursion result, recursion steps)` in this manner. My code adds all even numbers and returns the sum of all even numbers and number of recursive steps. If odd, then it returns 0 and number of recursive steps.

I am getting a Type Error in my value, step variables...why is that so?

```py
def get_sum_evens(numbers):
    if not numbers:
        return 0, 0
    elif numbers[0] % 2 == 0:
        value, step = get_sum_evens(numbers[1:])
        return numbers[0] + value, step + 1
    elif numbers[0] % 2 != 0:
        steps = get_sum_evens(numbers[1:])
        return 0, steps + 1
    
print(get_sum_evens([2, 3, 5, 6]))
print(get_sum_evens([]))
print(get_sum_evens([1, 3, 5, 7]))
print(get_sum_evens([9, 5, 15, 11, 23]))
```

Comment: There is no such error as a `TextError`. You're getting a `TypeError` since `steps` is a tuple and you're trying to sum a tuple and an int.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a TextError". This code produces `TypeError` instead. It is important to **show** errors; do not try to describe them from memory. Show [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) errors by copying and pasting, starting with the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end. As well, before posting, [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) to *read and understand* the error message. "and idk why?" is not helpful, because it does not tell us how to help you understand.

Comment: This question is a matter of elementary debugging. The goal is for `get_sum_evens` to return a tuple of two values, in every case - correct? Therefore, if you do `steps = get_sum_evens(numbers[1:])`, `steps` will be a tuple, right? Therefore, where the code says `return 0, steps + 1`, *how exactly do you expect this to work*? What should be added to the `1` in order to compute the desired result? (Hint: how did you handle this in the *other* `elif` branch?)

Comment: It should be `value, step = get_sum_evens(numbers[1:])` in both cases, even if you don't need `value`. Although I don't really understand the logic here.

Comment: @tobias_k it's purely a pedagogical exercise, I think. The intent is that the first value of the tuple will accumulate the sum of even numbers in the input, and the second will count the number of recursive calls that were made.

Comment: Note that the recursive algorithm is wrong. If it encounters an odd number it discards all the summed values so far and returns a zero. So, if the intention is to sum all evens, then `[2, 4, 1, 6, 8]` should be `20`, however the algorithm would return `6`, since it discards the sum of `6` and `8` as they follow an odd number.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean you got a `TypeError`, not "TextError".

```
steps = get_sum_evens(numbers[1:])
```

`steps` is now a tuple, and you're adding `+ 1` to it.

You'll always want to do:

```
value, steps = get_sum_evens(...)
```